JsonExtensions.Serializer fails to compile
I have a project that I'm in the process of converting from NET 6 to NET 8.
The NET 6 project uses the System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt v6.22 Nuget package. At one spot during startup, the project calls
JsonExtensions.Serializer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject;

The project compiles and works as expected, using Newtonsoft.Json for token serialization.
For NET 8, I upgraded the Nuget package to v 8.0.2 (which is the latest as of now). The above line now fails to compile, even though the documentation calls out to use that line to configure serialization.
I have a minimal project that uses NET 8 and the latest version of the package that now fails to build:
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;

namespace JwtJsonTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            JsonExtensions.Serializer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject; // Fails to compile

            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        }
    }
}

The error is: CS0103 The name 'JsonExtensions' does not exist in the current context.
This uses Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.1 and System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 8.0.2. Am I missing something? How should I configure the Microsoft package to use Newtonsoft.Json?
Note that I do not want to switch over to using System.Text.Json - this package serializes tokens slightly differently that breaks other projects that need to be compatible. It also lacks certain features for JSON serialization that we rely on.

"Fails to compile" presumably means there's an error message - your question should include it.

@JonSkeet I'm sorry, you're right. I updated the question with the error - it's just the JsonExtensions class seems to be missing.

Right - it looks like it was deleted in this commit: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/commit/be13ac5acbede3f287bcbe7057fe78927735faf2

And originally here: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/pull/2233

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/wiki/IdentityModel-7x discusses this a bit more, but it doesn't list the removal of JsonExtensions in the breaking changes, and doesn't suggest an alternative - sorry!

@JonSkeet Thank you for checking on it. I guess I need to get in touch with Microsoft.
